# Opening a position when the price is crossing a sma

Tags: pine-script

I'm new on pine script and I am trying to code a strategy that take a position once the price is crossing a simple moving average. But the thing is that I want the position to be taken at the sma price at the exact moment the price is crossing it.

Here the code I wrote for now :

```
strategy(title="My strategy", overlay=true, initial_capital=10000, precision=5, pyramiding=9999999999, calc_on_every_tick=true)

moving_average = ta.sma(close, 20)
plot(moving_average, color=color.blue, title="MA", offset=1)

strategy.entry("Buying Order", strategy.long, when= ta.cross(close, moving_average), limit=moving_average)
```

As you can see on the following picture :

[image]

The code is opening positions but not at the exact limit order price which should be at the sma value and at the time the price is crossing it. Also, the code is not opening a position every time the price is crossing the sma.

Could anyone help me to find a way to code this strategy ?

Answer (score 0):

Your strategy will be executed when the bar is closed. So, you can enter a trade on the previous bar's sma price. You cannot react on values based on the current bar as if your strategy was running on every tick on the historical bars.

See the [execution model](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Execution_model.html#calculation-based-on-historical-bars) for mor information.